# Make POST by href link

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a post through href link.I am using a dropdown menu which contains those links. The problem is that wherever click I get the same result as the first one. I want each link to post to the result that get from query with that id not to the first one.

```
<li>
  <?php  $rows=query("SELECT * FROM filmi") ?>
    <?php foreach($rows as $r):?>
      <form name="myform" method="post" action="description.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="
        <?=$r["id"]?>"/>
      </form>   
      <a href="description.php" onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit(); return false;">
        <?=$r["titulli"]?>
      </a>
  <?php endforeach?>    
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the same result as the first one

That's because you have multiple forms with the same name.  So your JavaScript reference to `document.forms['myform']` always finds the first one by that name.

Try making the name more dynamic.  In your `foreach` loop, append some unique record value (the record's ID should do nicely) to the `name="myform"` and, subsequently, to the JavaScript reference to that element.  That should make the form names unique and allow the JavaScript to reference the specific form you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a new form each time you run through a Foreach loop.  You're also using the same Input Field name for each interation.

Try this:

```
<li>
    <?php  $rows=query("SELECT * FROM filmi") ?>
     // Your form is opened and closed outside of the Foreach() loop.
     // This means all of your hidden fields will print within the same form.
     <form name="myform" method="post" action="description.php">
     <?php foreach($rows as $r):?>
           //  If you're expecting more than one id, you'll need to 
           //  post your form using array syntax.  Each "id" will be posted
           //  to PHP in incremented fashion.
           <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?=$r["id"]?>"/>                                           

      <a href="description.php" onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit(); return false;">   
    <?=$r["titulli"]?></a>                                          
    <?php endforeach?>  
        </form> 
    </li>
```

Comment: I don't know that "array syntax" is the appropriate term here.  Do let me know if there's a better way to put this.

Answer (score 0):

That appen because ALL of your forms have the same name, for do what you want you need to make the form (tag name) dynamic. like this for the name:

```
<?php $i = 0;?>
<?php foreach($rows as $r):?>
    <form name="myform<?php print $i;?>" method="post" action="description.php">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$r["id"]?>"/>                                           
    </form> 
    <a href="description.php" onclick="document.forms['myform<?php print $i;?>'].submit(); 
return false;">
<?php $i++;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms['myform'].submit()` will submit the form named "myform". You're creating `$rows` forms in that name, so what happens is that only the first one gets submited.

I'd suggest naming each one differently: (look at the form name, and the onclick event)

```
<li>
  <?php  $rows=query("SELECT * FROM filmi") ?>
    <?php foreach($rows as $r):?>
      <form name="myform<?=$r["id"]?>" method="post" action="description.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$r["id"]?>" />
      </form><a href="description.php" onclick="document.forms['myform<?=$r["id"]?>'].submit(); return false;">
        <?=$r["titulli"]?>
      </a>
  <?php endforeach?>    
</li>
```

Or, if they're always one after the other, simply posting the previousSibling.

```
<li>
  <?php  $rows=query("SELECT * FROM filmi") ?>
    <?php foreach($rows as $r):?>
      <form method="post" action="description.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$r["id"]?>" />
      </form><a href="description.php" onclick="this.previousSibling.submit(); return false;">
        <?=$r["titulli"]?>
      </a>
  <?php endforeach?>    
</li>
```